# How can i change host IP address in Gitlab

Tags: http, iis, header, gitlab, arr

I installed gitlab in my ubuntu server operated in Hyper-V. Surely, host is Windows Server that routing Hyper-V guests. My Ubuntu server and Hyper-V NIC have private IP addresses, "10.0.0.101" and "10.0.0.1". For routing to Hyper-V guest, I set IIS ARR and URL rewrite and it is operating well. But, in gitlab, Client's access URL(ex. git.example.com) is used for indicate "User profile URL" like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52hiH.png)

I think that it should not show "http://10.0.0.101/test", but "http://git.example.com/test" and I hope to change this. I changed ARR settings 
 like HTTP Header, and URL rewrite settings like Server variables. Eventually, however, it wasn't worked.

How can i change this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to edit your `GITLAB_CONFIG` (gitlab.rb)
If I open a users profile I get the right url.
I have set these settings:

```
external_url 'https://gitlab.example.com'
nginx['redirect_http_to_https'] = true
```

but I am running Gitlab under `https`, I am not sure if this changes something.

```
 nginx['ssl_client_certificate'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/ca.crt"
 nginx['ssl_certificate'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/gitlab.crt"
 nginx['ssl_certificate_key'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/gitlab.key"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I set 'external_url' but it wasn't worked. SSL connection has no problem because it is established by host's IIS. I want to set HTTP Header to modify access information which guest's nginx is recognizing as.